# Adding Camera Causes Crash on iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation

I'm getting reports of a crash in my camera-based app, but it seems to only be happening on iPhone X.

I can't understand why this is happening. The documentation for the function triggering the crash makes no mention of any exceptions that would be thrown and I can't find anything different about the iPhone X's camera compared to other devices. Any help will be appreciated!

This is the relevant code:

```swift
guard let camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back) else {
    print("no camera")
    return nil
}

let deviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput
do {
    deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera)
    session.addInputWithNoConnections(deviceInput)
} catch {
    print("no front input: \(error)")
    return nil
}

// CRASH HAPPENS HERE
guard let videoPort = deviceInput.ports(for: .video, sourceDeviceType: camera.deviceType, sourceDevicePosition: camera.position).first else {
    print("no front camera device input's video port")
    return nil
}
```

This is the symbolicated crash log (`CameraManager.addCamera` is the function containing the above code and the referenced line (117) is the `guard let videoPort = ...` crash location pointed out above):

```
Incident Identifier: ACA6411C-1323-4857-957E-613433C7C2AC
CrashReporter Key:   9898af27a5a7d0054c20dc251e2ccb4ed398b551
Hardware Model:      iPhone10,6
Process:             Maloufie [869]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DD268152-6131-4F0A-A895-F3C07ECDF17A/Maloufie.app/Maloufie
Identifier:          com.dylan.Maloufie
Version:             1.3 (1)
AppStoreTools:       14A305
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.dylan.Maloufie [766]

Date/Time:           2022-10-17 06:20:19.4589 -0700
Launch Time:         2022-10-17 06:20:19.3621 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 16.0.3 (20A392)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    5.03.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  1

Application Specific Information:
abort() called


Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x1c085adb4 __exceptionPreprocess + 160
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1bece59a0 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   AVFCapture                             0x1dcd729dc -[AVCaptureFigVideoDevice setExposureMode:] + 0
3   Maloufie                               0x1040f85f4 CameraManager.addCamera(_:) + 67060 (CameraManager.swift:117)
4   Maloufie                               0x1040f8100 closure #1 in CameraManager.configure() + 65792 (CameraManager.swift:98)
5   Maloufie                               0x1040f0a9c thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 35484 (<compiler-generated>:0)
6   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1cc3f2850 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
7   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1cc3f37c8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1cc3ce854 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$armv81 + 604
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1cc3cf2e4 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 380
10  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1cc3d9000 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 612
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20c90cb50 _pthread_wqthread + 284
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20c90c67c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   SwiftUI                                0x1c9f7b7d4 0x1c8df5000 + 18376660
1   SwiftUI                                0x1c9f75568 0x1c8df5000 + 18351464
2   SwiftUI                                0x1c9f7aa64 0x1c8df5000 + 18373220
3   SwiftUI                                0x1c8f06e50 0x1c8df5000 + 1121872
4   SwiftUI                                0x1c9f74e68 0x1c8df5000 + 18349672
5   SwiftUI                                0x1c8dfa078 0x1c8df5000 + 20600
6   SwiftUI                                0x1c9aceb70 0x1c8df5000 + 13474672
7   SwiftUI                                0x1c9579d44 0x1c8df5000 + 7884100
8   SwiftUI                                0x1c8e1e784 0x1c8df5000 + 169860
9   SwiftUI                                0x1c8e4de4c 0x1c8df5000 + 364108
10  SwiftUI                                0x1c8e2550c 0x1c8df5000 + 197900
11  SwiftUI                                0x1c8e4dc44 0x1c8df5000 + 363588
12  SwiftUI                                0x1c8e2550c 0x1c8df5000 + 197900
13  SwiftUI                                0x1c9ace8c0 0x1c8df5000 + 13473984
14  SwiftUI                                0x1c9ace700 0x1c8df5000 + 13473536
15  SwiftUI                                0x1c9be1d74 0x1c8df5000 + 14601588
16  SwiftUI                                0x1c9423d48 0x1c8df5000 + 6483272
17  SwiftUI                                0x1c9425f6c 0x1c8df5000 + 6492012
18  SwiftUI                                0x1c8eab868 0x1c8df5000 + 747624
19  SwiftUI                                0x1c8fce550 0x1c8df5000 + 1938768
20  UIKitCore                              0x1c7769478 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 68
21  SwiftUI                                0x1c8e4b8e4 0x1c8df5000 + 354532
22  SwiftUI                                0x1c8e0f98c 0x1c8df5000 + 108940
23  SwiftUI                                0x1c8ea085c 0x1c8df5000 + 702556
24  SwiftUI                                0x1c8e1f644 0x1c8df5000 + 173636
25  SwiftUI                                0x1c8e22968 0x1c8df5000 + 186728
26  UIKitCore                              0x1c773ea58 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1920
27  QuartzCore                             0x1c6c63a60 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 496
28  QuartzCore                             0x1c6c764cc CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 144
29  QuartzCore                             0x1c6c870bc CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 464
30  QuartzCore                             0x1c6cbb58c CA::Transaction::commit() + 652
31  UIKitCore                              0x1c7b9656c __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 32
32  CoreFoundation                         0x1c089162c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 20
33  CoreFoundation                         0x1c08f51a8 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 364
34  CoreFoundation                         0x1c08c8244 __CFRunLoopRun + 800
35  CoreFoundation                         0x1c08ccdfc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 584
36  GraphicsServices                       0x1fa782984 GSEventRunModal + 160
37  UIKitCore                              0x1c7ab0e7c -[UIApplication _run] + 868
38  UIKitCore                              0x1c7ab0af4 UIApplicationMain + 312
39  SwiftUI                                0x1c8f90940 0x1c8df5000 + 1685824
40  SwiftUI                                0x1c8f03ba0 0x1c8df5000 + 1108896
41  SwiftUI                                0x1c8ef000c 0x1c8df5000 + 1028108
42  Maloufie                               0x1040efaf4 main + 31476 (DefaultsStore.swift:0)
43  dyld                                   0x1e1f8ade0 start + 2080

Thread 1 name:   Dispatch queue: com.dylan.SessionQ
Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1fdd4c2f4 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20c918654 pthread_kill + 208
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x1cc432e9c abort + 124
3   libc++abi.dylib                        0x20c852dec abort_message + 128
4   libc++abi.dylib                        0x20c84365c demangling_terminate_handler() + 300
5   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1beceb1c4 _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                        0x20c852288 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                        0x20c852230 std::terminate() + 52
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1cc3f37dc _dispatch_client_callout + 36
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1cc3ce854 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$armv81 + 604
10  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1cc3cf2e4 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 380
11  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1cc3d9000 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 612
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20c90cb50 _pthread_wqthread + 284
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20c90c67c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20c90c674 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20c90c674 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20c90c674 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1fdd46194 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1fdd57a08 mach_msg2_internal + 76
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1fdd57c44 mach_msg_overwrite + 384
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1fdd46688 mach_msg + 20
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1c08c7244 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 156
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1c08c83f4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1232
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1c08ccdfc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 584
7   Foundation                             0x1bfc2f3fc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 208
8   Foundation                             0x1bfc2f2f8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 60
9   UIKitCore                              0x1c7bd56d0 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 424
10  Foundation                             0x1bfc46f44 __NSThread__start__ + 704
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20c90e060 _pthread_start + 116
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20c90c688 thread_start + 8

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20c90c674 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20c90c674 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20c90c674 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 1 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x000000020c855ea1   x5: 0x000000016bd9e430   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffff00000400
    x8: 0x000000016bd9f000   x9: 0x3c7ae18321bb5c99  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x000000000000000b
   x12: 0x000000000000000b  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000002  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000f0b  x21: 0x000000016bd9f0e0  x22: 0x000000016bd9f0e0  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000282d442e8  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000000000114
   x28: 0x0000000281650a80   fp: 0x000000016bd9e3a0   lr: 0x000000020c918654
    sp: 0x000000016bd9e380   pc: 0x00000001fdd4c2f4 cpsr: 0x40000000
   far: 0x000000021c514430  esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
       0x1c8df5000 -        0x1ca2dffff SwiftUI arm64  <03f678aed39a3db88001f994dd375024> /System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI
       0x1c773a000 -        0x1c8df4fff UIKitCore arm64  <0a5f2ff1a67f3263bafc1224b1501a17> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
       0x1c6c5a000 -        0x1c6f86fff QuartzCore arm64  <27270b31fdb434b8acde7a118d9f3c5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
       0x1c0851000 -        0x1c0c1cfff CoreFoundation arm64  <5f4831c9494934eab3733f45c312b753> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
       0x1fa781000 -        0x1fa789fff GraphicsServices arm64  <df370b2c9baa33c8ba00b54d2f4538dc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
       0x1040e8000 -        0x1040fffff Maloufie arm64  <b17c7c22b5e639be9a8421e1233c7121> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DD268152-6131-4F0A-A895-F3C07ECDF17A/Maloufie.app/Maloufie
       0x1e1f77000 -        0x1e1ff0dcb dyld arm64  <761f47f5a57031c3ac49af3ded335020> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x1fdd45000 -        0x1fdd7afef libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <146974c516ed354ab334ee8730c3b715> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x20c90b000 -        0x20c91bfff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <ad80420a2ce3395ebfe7386912138296> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
       0x1cc413000 -        0x1cc48efff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <637814c516103a04b2544eb2b26b750b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
       0x20c842000 -        0x20c858ffb libc++abi.dylib arm64  <b2aff428242e3f0e99621ca63ca8fa10> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
       0x1becd0000 -        0x1bed0ac9f libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <661c3febed903377864fe35f30e1e644> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
       0x1cc38f000 -        0x1cc412fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <abe14ca70020314dbba65f92f0bbb1c4> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
       0x1bfbf1000 -        0x1c049dfff Foundation arm64  <0b0d93617efa31da95246f4a7412b618> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
       0x1dcd3e000 -        0x1dce30fff AVFCapture arm64  <212ca108e55d3a429861cd676dede25d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVFCapture.framework/AVFCapture

EOF
```

Comment: Is it just x or x and below? If it is x and below you are using something that requires a newer chip. I think it is A12+ there are many camera functions that require it. You will have to exclude the feature from devices that are not compatible.

Comment: The crash log and your information about what line 117 of CameraManager.swift is do not match. Are you sure they are both from the same version of the app? The crashing line should look like `camera.exposureMode = ...`. And a reason this line crashes is that `lockForConfiguration()` has not been called.

Comment: @loremipsum Just X being reported right now

Comment: @Codo That's the weird bit, I'm never actually setting the `exposureMode`, and I don't understand why the `ports` call isn't listed in my crash log. The code posted above is the full contents of `CameraManager.addCamera` (up to the point of the line (supposedly) causing the crash and the line I highlighted is indeed the one being called out in the crash log.

Comment: Could it be a memory corruption? Have you run it with Xcode's address sanitizer and similar tools?